# How google home app works?

Tags: wi-fi, google, networking, android-things

I am developing a new iot project to monitor air quality in the environment. the device, ESP8266, needs a wi-fi connection, which we usually put fixed in the code that the microcontroller will run, which is not legal, because if I need to change the network for some reason, I will have to change the source code.

Other IOT devices have the same situation, and manufacturers like Google, are able to configure the wifi on the device via the android phone or iphone. Like?

Apparently the device creates an access point and the cell phone, through the google home app, connects to this network and makes the configuration. The most intriguing thing for me is that he doesn't use a password.

I can access an access point from my device, make a POST call to a service and set the SSID and password credentials, but I need to enter that password. The Google Home app doesn't need this, as long as I'm connected to the same network.

Ex: my home local network is 2.4_2906. I bought a new google home mini and I want to connect it to this wi-fi network in my house. My Android device is connected to the 5.0_2906 network on the same router as the 2.4_2906. When trying to connect google home on the 2.4_2906 network, google says I'm not connected to it and asks me to connect, so I logged in there and I try to configure google home to use it too, and I can do it without saying it google home the network password.

How can I implement this for my device?

Comment: Typically the default Wifi hotspot opened by a device uses a static/know password. Therefore you don't have to enter it. Another option often used by cheap China device is to morse the data to the new device. In this case the encrypted Wifi is used to send packets of a certain length and as the length is not encrypted it can be used to transmit  small amount of data as a broadcast to all Wifi device within reception range.

Comment: If two devices are connected to the same network you can simply send a broadcast to all devices for device discovery. Only the devices listening for the broadcast plus understand the data format are able to answer such a call. Of course this is not the only way to discover devices.